# Exception with Custom expression builder with ICollection / IEnumerable

Tags: c#, expression, ienumerable, icollection

I have been trying to write a method that will build an expression based on types and parameters passed in. Currently the method is:

```
// tuple: CollectionName, ClassName, PropertyName
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildCollectionWithLike<T, TSub>(Dictionary<Tuple<string, string, string>, string> properties)
{
    // each one should generate something like: 
    //      x => x.PreviousSKUs.Where(y => y.PreviousSku.Contains("a"))

    try
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

        foreach (var key in properties.Keys)
        {
            var collectionType = typeof(TSub);
            var yParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSub), "y");

            var propertyExp = Expression.Property(yParameter, key.Item3);
            MethodInfo methodContains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
            var someValue = Expression.Constant(properties[key], typeof(string));
            var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, methodContains, someValue);

            var whereProperty = type.GetProperty(key.Item1);
            var wherePropertyExp = Expression.Property(xParameter, whereProperty);

            Func<IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool>, IEnumerable<T>> whereDelegate = Enumerable.Where;
            MethodInfo whereMethodInfo = whereDelegate.Method;

            var whereMethodExp = Expression.Call(whereMethodInfo, wherePropertyExp, containsMethodExp);

            expressions.Add(whereMethodExp);
        }

        Expression final = expressions.First();
        foreach (var expression in expressions.Skip(1))
        {
            final = Expression.Or(final, expression);
        }

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate =
            (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(final, xParameter);

        return predicate;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However at this line:

```
 var whereMethodExp = Expression.Call(whereMethodInfo, wherePropertyExp, containsMethodExp);
```

I get this exception:

```
Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Model.ProductPreviousSku]' 
    cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.Product]' 
    of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.Product] Where[Product](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.Product], System.Func`2[Model.Product,System.Boolean])'"
```

My class Model.Product has a property of type ICollection called PreviousSKUs.

I have a class called ProductPreviousSku which has a property of type string called PreviousSku.

As per my comment in at the start of the method I am trying to get this method to be able to construct an expression inside the foreach loop that looks like:

```
x => x.PreviousSKUs.Where(y => y.PreviousSku.Contains("a"))
```

I'm struggling to get passed this error at the moment so any help would be fantastic !

Comment: What specific problem do you have? Do you understand what the error means? Did you check the inputs to `Call` using the debugger?

Comment: The entire Exception message is: "Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Model.ProductPreviousSku]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.Product]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.Product] Where[Product](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.Product], System.Func`2[Model.Product,System.Boolean])'"

Comment: The inputs to Exception.Call do appear correct/appropriate. I think it's because my property is of type ICollection<> and not IEnumerable but I don't know how to work around this

Comment: What do you want to happen? You just cannot cast one type to the other. You have to convert. *You* define how that conversion happens. It is a semantic decision.

Comment: Yes, I understand I have to convert but can't seem to manage it. I'm also wondering if I have my Func correct. I now have:    Func<IEnumerable<TSub>, Func<TSub, bool>, IEnumerable<TSub>> whereDelegate = Enumerable.Where;
                    MethodInfo whereMethodInfo = whereDelegate.Method;                                                            

                    var whereMethodExp = Expression.Call(whereMethodInfo, wherePropertyExp, containsMethodExp);                     But this returns a different exception:

Comment: Exception message: "Expression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[Model.ProductPreviousSku,System.Boolean]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.ProductPreviousSku] Where[ProductPreviousSku](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Model.ProductPreviousSku], System.Func`2[Model.ProductPreviousSku,System.Boolean])'"